# KeyDown and keyUp not saving multiple keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a simple tetris application where I have the gameoby with the buttons to click.

Currently it is a react application and the way I handle the clicks is defined below:

```
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState([])

  const onKeydown = (e) => {
    const currentKey = e.key.toLowerCase()
    const localKeyPressed = [...keyPressed]
    localKeyPressed.push(currentKey)
    setKeyPressed(localKeyPressed)
  }

  const onKeyUp = (e) => {
    const currentKey = e.key.toLowerCase()
    const localKeyPressed = keyPressed
    localKeyPressed.pop(currentKey)
    setKeyPressed(localKeyPressed)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeydown)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeydown)
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)
    }
  }, [])
```

I want to have an array that when I press 2 consecutive keys (ex: 'A', 'B') I get this [A, B] currently It is not happeing I just get [A] [B] don't know exactly why.

Any help regarding this topic?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the callback form of the setter. `setKeyPressed(previous => [...previous, localKeyPressed])` Within this callback `previous` is ensured to be the latest updated version of `keyPressed`. If you don't use the callback `keyPressed` might be a stale value. As a rule of thumb, if the new state depends upon the old state, use the callback variant.

Comment: try `window.addEventListener...` instead of `document...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler functions are dependant on the current state `keyPressed`. When you attach them to the events in `useEffect`, the functions point to the original `keyPressed` state, which is an empty array. Whenever you update the state, you add the current, for example 'A' to the empty array, and set it as the new state.

The `useEffect` dependency array is empty, so it won't be called again until the component is unmounted. One solution is to add the functions to the dependencies array, so the event handlers would be added and removed on each render. The other option is to avoid the need for dependencies. When the new state is dependant on the previous state, use the [functional updates](http://%3Cscript%20crossorigin%20src=%22https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E%20%3Cscript%20crossorigin%20src=%22https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E) form of `useState` to avoid the need to use the previous state as a dependency.

In addition, don't mutate the state in `onKeyUp`, because `const localKeyPressed = keyPressed` doesn't clone the original state, so use array spread to do so.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const Demo = () => {
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const onKeydown = e => {
      setKeyPressed(oldState => [
        ...oldState,
        e.key.toLowerCase()
      ]) 
    }

    const onKeyUp = e => {
      setKeyPressed(oldState => {
        const newState = [...oldState]
        
        newState.pop()

        return newState
      }) 
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeydown)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeydown)
      document.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
    {
      JSON.stringify(keyPressed)
    }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```